# Leer un archivo csv con sscanf

Tags: c, archivo, csv

Estoy intentando leer todos los valores de un archivo csv para tenerlo en memoria y asi usarlo en el programa, estoy leyendo linea por linea ignorando las dos primeras lineas donde esta la cabecera por asi decirlo y una instruccion para separar por commas por defecto. El problema es que cuando consigo leer la linea completa, al usar sscanf para leer los valores de cada campo no me los lee de manera correcta.

Esta es la parte del codigo donde ocurre:

```
 rewind(csv_file);
    char buff[1024];
    while(fgets(buff, 1024, csv_file)){
        if(lines >2 ){
            clients c;
            sscanf(buff,"%21s,%21s,%12s,%12s,%51s,%31s,%26s", c.name, c.last_name, c.telf, c.cel, c.email, c.city, c.country);
            push(clients_array, (lines-3),  c);
        }
        lines++;
    }
}
```

Cuando hago printf de la linea (`buff`), me retorna esto:

```
carlos,rodriguez,04242355871,02123311120,carlos@hotmail.com,caracas,venezuela
```

y si hago printf de el valor de `c.name` me retorna esto:

```
carlos,rodriguez,04242355871,02123311120,carlos@hotmail.com,caracas,venezuela
```

igual a la linea `buff`

al parecer el formato utilizado para sscanf esta mal por que no me lee la linea completamente como debe ser evitando las comas. Como se realiza correctamente?

Asi es como se ve el archivo csv abierto desde un editor de texto:

Clientes.csv:

```
  sep=,
Nombre,Apellido,Telefono,Celular,Correo electronico,Ciudad,Pais
carlos,rodriguez,04242355871,02123311120,carlos@hotmail.com,caracas,venezuela
```

Comment: ¿Qué te retorna `c.name`? Se te ha olvidado esa parte

Comment: c.name me retorna la linea completa de buff, es decir carlos,rodriguez,04242355871,02123311120,carlos@hotmail.com,caracas,venezuela es el valor de c.name, y ya los otros valores de c.last_name, c.telf ... estan vacios o con el string de buff truncado a la mitad.

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir tu propósito debes usar:

- `strtok()`: Esta función te permite trocear un string a partir de un delimitador dado. Lo que hace, básicamente, es modificar el string original reemplazando el delimitador por un finalizador de cadena.
- `strcpy()`: Para copiar la subcadena resultante en la variable que te interesa

El código podría quedar así:

```
strcpy(c.name,      strtok(buff, ','));
strcpy(c.last_name, strtok(NULL, ','));
strcpy(c.telf,      strtok(NULL, ','));
// ...
```

Nota que `strtok` únicamente recibe `buff` la primera vez, en el resto de llamadas debe recibir `NULL` (o `0`). Esto le indica a `strtok` que debe seguir troceando la cadena.